# Accessing Entity Framework from Timer Job: connection string problem

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job, database-connection

I had a DB that normally I access from my SharePoint (2010) custom feature by Entity Framework.
The connection string is stored in the web.config.

If I do something like that from outside TimerJob:

```
using (DB db = new DB()) { }
```

I get a working instance, if I do the same thing from TimerJob I get exception. To avoid this I stored a connection string into my "Configuration List" so that my code now is:

```
string cs = //GET STRING FROM LIST
using (DB db = new DB(cs)) { }
```

but this generates me an exception.

Where is the problem?

I tried with these connection string:
    metadata=res://*/NewDB.csdl|res://*/NewDB.ssdl|res://*/NewDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CNH_MW;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework'

OR

metadata=res://*/NewDB.csdl|res://*/NewDB.ssdl|res://*/NewDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CNH_MW;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"

without any success..

```
Exception: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid
Stacktrace:    at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
```

at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName) 
   at CNH.WorkFlowManufacturing.CNH_MW..ctor() 
   at CNH.WorkFlowManufacturing.DBHandler.get_GetCNH_MW() 
   at CNH.WorkFlowManufacturing.JobImportazione.ImportaFile(SPFile file, SqlConnection& conn, Int32 PK_LOG) 
   at CNH.WorkFlowManufacturing.JobImportazione.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please add the message/stack from the exception you are experiencing?

Comment: Added right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OWSTIMER doesn't run in a web context and does not have immediate access to your web application web.config files.

You can use something like this tutorial to read web.config values from your web apps: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/12/access-webconfig-in-sharepoint-timer.html

You can also create an app.config file right next to the OWSTIMER.exe file (would be owstimer.exe.config).

And lastly, you could store that data in a different fashion (i.e. Farm Properties in the Object Model).

**EDIT**: Here is an example of creating the OWSTIMER config file: http://doitwithsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/03/config-file-for-sharepoint-custom-timer.html